# Stream iPhone radio to Mac mini

Tags: iphone, mac

I have at Mac mini hooked up to a plain stereo amplifier + speakers and would like to stream some of the radio apps I have installed  on my iPhone to my Mac mini and play the music through the speakers without having to turn on my tv. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Rogue Amoeba's AirFoil and AirFoil Speakers applications will allow you to do this.